# How to get this regex to accept no more than 1 special character

Tags: regex

`^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()-_=+{[}\]:;'<,>.?\/]).{8,}$`

`?=.*` I understand is saying Match any of these characters an unlimited amount of times.

I took out the `.*` but it is not working as expected and is validating the following string: `` *OeuH5c#i`m$0\\\H2e&#.?* `` as being valid.

I also followed the character list in brackets with `{1}` to specifically state I only want one character but that does not work either..

Without the `.*` shouldn't this essentially pass only if 1 of the special characters is found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=\w*[-!@#$%^&*()_=+{[}\]:;'<,>.?\/]\w*$).{8,}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fF5qI5/2)

1. Surround special character class wit `\w*` o either side to make sure there is only on special character.
2. Keep unescaped hyphen at first or last position in character class